# How do I get the correct format x-axis for my phpspreadsheet chart?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am using 33_Chart_create_scatter.php to make a two line xyScatter chart. Everything is going well, except, the x-axis is not formatting as I would like it to. There is no associated error involver. Only a poor x-axis. See the first image. For the correct (desired) x-axis, see the second image. Can someone help me achive the proper x-axis format? 
I got the correct format x-axis by simply right clicking the chart area and selecting "Change Chart Type". Then I select (already selected) "X Y (Scatter)" and "ok". The x-axis is changed to that shown in my correct x-axis image. So, that brings about my second question, if I can not get a code correction to get the proper x-axis format, can we include macro's in our create charts? A simple three line auto_open macro included will yield the proper chart/x-axis when the new spreadsheet is opened.

I've used both horizontal and vertical selections for source values. I've also tried using specific values for the source. See J1:R1 in my image. I can not figure out how to add my images. So, incorrect x-axis runs from 1 to about 50 by 1's And it looks like there maybe two to three sets of numbers all crunched together. The correct scale is 0 to 40 by 5's evenly spaced. this is a minutes scale. The y scale looks perfect.

Here is the code involved.

$xAxisTickValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER,                     'Worksheet!$C$1:$C$18', null, 18),
    new 
    DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$F$1:$F$18', null, 18)
   ];[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code should control the x and y properties. I am able to control all the properties of the Y-axis. How ever it appears the x-axis min and max values are controlled by the x Axis Tick Values. If I don't use x Axis Tick Values, It then appears x-axis min and max values are controlled by the number of y data points?
What do I have to do so this code can be used to control x-axis min and max values?

```
$xaxis = new Axis();
$xaxis->setAxisOptionsProperties('low', 0, 'autoZero', null, 'in', 'out', 0, 40, 5, 0);

$title = new Title('Calorimetric Calibration');
$yAxisLabel = new Title(html_entity_decode('Temp (&deg;C)',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$xAxisLabel = new Title('Time (Min)');

// Create the chart  
$chart = new Chart(
    'chart1', // name
    $title, // title
    $legend, // legend
    $plotArea, // plotArea
    true, // plotVisibleOnly
    0, // displayBlanksAs
    $xAxisLabel, // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel,  // yAxisLabel
    $yaxis, 
    $xaxis,
    null, 
    null
);
```